# PHP Post not working with Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, post

I have a simple form:
`<form id="formTest" name="formTest" action="" method="get">`
    `<input id="txtPostcode" name="Postcode" type="text" class="txtBoxSmall" />`
    `<input type="button" name="SubmitTheForm" id="btnSubmit" onClick="TestAjax()" value="submit" />`
`</form>`

My Javascript code is:

```
function TestAjax(){
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {

        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("GET","autocomplete.php?value1=aaaaa&value2=fffff",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

My problem is that in the php file autocomplete.php i can not access the txtPostcode element like so:

```
$postcodetext = $_GET[Postcode];
```

But if i get rid of the javascript function in the submit button, and add action="autocomplete.php" 
to the form tag it will work, but then of course it is not ajaxed. Can someone tell me why I cant get any
values from $_GET[Postcode] when ajaxing?? I know i can just pass the value of the txtPostcode in the URL,
but i dont want to do it that way, is there something i can do so i can access the textbox via the 
$_GET[Postcode] call in php??

Thanks.

Comment: In the future, it would be useful to format your code when you post questions/answers/comments. Read the help here: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Note that you can edit your posts to format after you posted.

Comment: That isn't a POST, it's a GET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change this line:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","autocomplete.php?value1=aaaaa&value2=fffff",true);
```

to include all the values you want to get in `$_GET[]` in PHP. You can do:

```
var postcode = document.getElementById('txtPostcode').value;
xmlhttp.open("GET","autocomplete.php?value1=aaaaa&value2=fffff&Postcode=" + postcode,true);
```

and similar for any additional things you want to access in PHP.

I totally agree with the comments below - take a look at jQuery, it will make your life much easier. Start here for example:

- http://docs.jquery.com/How_jQuery_Works

Comment: Icyrock is right in that is how you'd fix your code, but unless you have a strong reason not to use a javascript library, I'd strongly recommend using jQuery or Prototype to ease the pain of working in Ajax.

Comment: xmlhttp.open("GET","..."); will create new ajax request to page instead of submitting the form values directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. This is the first time I've ever used a forum, you guys are quick to respond, cheers.